# Mechanize in Module, Nameerror ' agent'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

Looking for advice on how to fix this error and refactor this code to improve it.

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'pry'
require 'pp'




module Mymodule
  class WebBot 

    agent = Mechanize.new { |agent| 
        agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Chrome'
    }

    def form(response)
      require "addressable/uri"
      require "addressable/template"
      template = Addressable::Template.new("http://www.domain.com/{?query*}")
      url = template.expand({"query" => response}).to_s
      page = agent.get(url)  
    end 

    def get_products
      products = []
      page.search("datatable").search('tr').each do |row|
        begin
          product =  row.search('td')[1].text
        rescue => e
            p e.message
        end
        products << product
      end  
      products
    end  
  end 
end
```

## Calling the module:

```
response = {size: "SM", color: "BLUE"}

t = Mymodule::WebBot.new
t.form(response)
t.get_products
```

## Error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `agent'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby has a naming convention. `agent` is a *local variable* in the class scope. To make it visible to other methods you should make it a *class variable* by naming it `@@agent`, and it'll be shared among all the objects of `WebBot`. The preferred way though is to make it an *instance variable* by naming it `@agent`. Every object of `WebBot` will have its own `@agent`. But you should put it in `initialize`, `initialize` will be invoked when you create a new object with `new`

```
class WebBot
  def initialize
    @agent = Mechanize.new do |a|
      a.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Chrome'
    end
  end
.....
```

And the same error will occur to `page`. You defined it in `form` as a *local variable*. When `form` finishes execution, it'll be deleted. You should make it an *instance variable*. Fortunately, you don't have to put it in `initialize`. You can define it here in `form`. And the object will have its own `@page` after invoking `form`. Do this in `form`:

```
def form(response)
  require "addressable/uri"
  require "addressable/template"
  template = Addressable::Template.new("http://www.domain.com/{?query*}")
  url = template.expand({"query" => response}).to_s
  @page = agent.get(url)  
end
```

And remember to change every occurrence of `page` and `agent` to `@page` and `@agent`. In your `get_products` for example:

```
def get_products
  products = []
  @page.search("datatable").search('tr').each do |row|
  .....
```

These changes will resolve the name errors. Refactoring is another story btw.

Comment: Yes. Totally true. I'm gonna fix it.

Comment: Works, great, thank you.  Any advice on cleaning up the code?